# Searching for largest rectangle with even count of numbers in matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I have an a*b matrix of numbers (from 0 to 9), for example

```
[[1,2,3],
 [4,5,6],
 [7,6,5]]
```

And I want to find the largest rectagle, where is count of each number even (in this example, the result will be)

```
[[5,6],
 [6,5]]  -- numbers 5 an 6 are here 2 times
```

Is here any way, how to find it in n*log(n) or better time where n is count of items in matrix (n = a*b)? (If that rectagle doesn't exist, the result will be an empty set)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a second matrix in O(N) time (where N is the number of cells), which can then be used to check whether a certain rectangle has an even number of every digit in O(1) time. The number of candidate rectangles is however related to N<sup>2</sup>, so the worst case will be O(N<sup>2</sup>). You could use dynamic programming and build up from smaller rectangles to larger ones, but because we're looking for the largest rectangle, that may be counter-productive for the average case. *(Update: I suspect that the worst case, a matrix with no valid rectangles, is impossible for square input larger than 63x63; see below.)*

We'll create a second matrix holding 10-bit integers, where each bit indicates whether there is an even or odd number of a certain digit in the rectangle from that position to the bottom-right corner. We'll start with the bottom-right corner, and work our way up to the top-left corner, using the adjacent integers we've already added to calculate the new ones:

```
2 8 6 5    ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  
3 2 1 4    ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  
1 3 2 5    ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  
7 2 0 9    ----------  ----------  ----------  1000000000
```

The integer for the bottom-right corner has its 9th bit set, because the value at that position is 9. Then we calculate the two adjacent edge positions:

```
2 8 6 5    ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  
3 2 1 4    ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  
1 3 2 5    ----------  ----------  ----------  1000100000  
7 2 0 9    ----------  ----------  1000000001  1000000000
```

In general, we can calculate the bit pattern by setting the bit that corresponds to the position's value, and xor-ing this pattern with the three adjacent patterns to the right, bottom, and bottom-right of the current position:

```
position (2,2): 0000000100 (value = 2)
position (3,2): 1000100000
position (2,3): 1000000001
position (3,3): 1000000000
XOR:            1000100101
```

```
2 8 6 5    ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  
3 2 1 4    ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  
1 3 2 5    ----------  ----------  1000100101  1000100000  
7 2 0 9    ----------  ----------  1000000001  1000000000
```

For positions along the right and bottom edges, we only xor with one adjacent pattern, under or to the right of the current position. Eventually we get this matrix:

```
2 8 6 5    1111010001  1101011111  1001010111  1000010000  
3 2 1 4    1010110101  1000111111  1000110111  1000110000  
1 3 2 5    1010101011  1000101001  1000100101  1000100000  
7 2 0 9    1010000101  1000000101  1000000001  1000000000
```

With this matrix, we can now check whether any rectangle has an even number of every digit, by xor-ing its top-left pattern with the pattern under it, to the right of it, and to the bottom-right of it:

```
- - - -    ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------    
3 2 1 -    1010110101  ----------  ----------  1000110000  
1 3 2 -    ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------    
- - - -    1010000101  ----------  ----------  1000000000
```

```
position (0,1): 1010110101
position (3,1): 1000110000
position (0,3): 1010000101
position (3,3): 1000000000
XOR:            0000000000  <-  0 means even number of all digits
```

For rectangles up to the right or bottom edge, only two patterns are xor-ed. For rectangles up to the bottom-right corner, the pattern can simply be read from the matrix.

```
- - - -    ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------    
3 2 1 4    1010110101  ----------  ----------  ----------  
1 3 2 5    ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------    
- - - -    1010000101  ----------  ----------  ----------
```

```
position (0,1): 1010110101
position (0,3): 1010000101
XOR:            0000110000  <-  non-zero means odd number of some digits
```

We'd then proceed by checking the whole rectangle, then the rectangles one row or column smaller, and so on, from large to small. Obviously, rectangles with an odd number of rows and columns can be skipped.

The worst case complexity of this is N<sup>2</sup> (if the last rectangle we check is the only valid solution). The best case is N (if the whole rectangle is a valid solution) and the average depends on the specifics of the input.

If you want to try dynamic programming, build a table with the bit patterns for every 2x1 and 1x2 rectangle, then xor two of these to build up 4x1, 1x4 and 2x2 rectangles, and so on... This requires xor-ing 2 patterns per rectangle, whereas the non-dp solution requires xor-ing 4 patterns (or 2 or 0 for rectangles up to the right or bottom edge), so I don't expect  major improvement. Also, if one of the largest rectangles is a valid solution, it would be found quickly in the non-dp solution, but only after calculating most of the rectangles in the dp solution.

---

I've done some tests with a simple Javascript implementation, and found that while the theoretical worst case (checking every rectangle with an even number of elements) indeed has a complexity of O(N<sup>2</sup>), the average case (when checking only rectangles larger than the current best solution) with random input levels off at around 1314 for rectangles sized 48x48 and larger. So the average case complexity is O(N) because building the second matrix becomes the dominant factor; large cases like 2048x2048 can be run in under a second.

```
  size       N       worst   average    max

  2x2        4           5       4        5
  3x3        9          20      14       20
  4x4       16          64      40       64
  5x5       25         144      81      144
  6x6       36         297     155      297
  7x7       49         528     250      528
  8x8       64         896     375      896
  9x9       81       1,400     496    1,355
 10x10     100       2,125     614    1,981
 11x11     121       3,060     698    2,876
 12x12     144       4,320     770    3,883
 13x13     169       5,880     815    5,098
 14x14     196       7,889     866    6,603
 15x15     225      10,304     897    7,729
 16x16     256      13,312     937    8,123
  ...
 20x20     400      32,000   1,057    9,019
 24x24     576      65,664   1,144    9,640
 32x32   1,024     204,800   1,248   10,521
 40x40   1,600     496,000   1,293   10,369
 48x48   2,304   1,022,976   1,306   11,006
 64x64   4,096   3,211,264   1,314   11,334
 80x80   6,400   7,808,000   1,314   10,962
 96x96   9,216  16,146,432   1,312   10,970
128x128 16,384  50,855,936   1,318   10,875
```

*The column "worst" shows the number of rectangles with an even-sized area; in the worst case, all these rectangles would have to be checked. The column "average" shows the average number of rectangles that actually needed to be checked in a test with random data, when going from large to small and skipping rectangles that are not larger than the largest valid rectangle found so far. The column "max" shows the actual worst case that was encountered in the test; this also seems to level off above 48x48. (Algorithm tested 1,000,000 times for each size, using random values.)*

[image]

The average number of rectangles that have to be checked is of course related to the fact that a large rectangle with random digits has a probability of around 1/2 of having an even number of a certain digit (but only an even number of digits can be present an even number of times) and thus 1/(C(10,0) + C(10,2) + C(10,4) + C(10,6) + C(10,8) + C(10,10)) or 1/512 of having an even number of all ten digits. The fact that I get an average of 1314 instead of 512 is probably because my algorithm doesn't strictly go from large to small rectangles, but tries 10x10 first, and then 9x10, 10x9, 8x10, 10x8 ... 1x10, 10x1, before switching to 8x9, 9x8, 6x9, 9x6 ... 2x9, 9x2, and then 8x8, 7x8, 8x7 ... to keep the code simple. If it were completely optimized, I'd expect the average to approach 512 for large rectangles.

---

When trying to find out whether the worst case, a matrix with no valid rectangles, was possible at large matrix sizes, I automatically arrived at squares based on this sequence:

```
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5...
```

which you get by repeating the sequence so far, and adding 1 to the last number ([OEIS A007814](https://oeis.org/A007814)). This results in these matrices which contain no rectangles with even numbers of each digit:

```
0,1
1,2
```

```
0,1,0,2
1,2,1,3
0,1,0,2
2,3,2,4
```

```
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3
3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6
```

```
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4
3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,7
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4
4,5,4,6,4,5,4,7,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,8
```

At his point, if you repeat the 16x16 matrix to create a 32x32 matrix and add 1 to the right-most column and bottom row, the bottom-right cell would have the value 10; we can replace this with a 1 (but that's the only value that works):

```
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,7
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,7,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,8
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,7
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
4,5,4,6,4,5,4,7,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,8,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,7,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,9
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,7
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,7,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,8
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,7
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5
5,6,5,7,5,6,5,8,5,6,5,7,5,6,5,9,5,6,5,7,5,6,5,8,5,6,5,7,5,6,5,1
```

Then, when going from 32x32 to 64x64, there are several cells in the right-most column and bottom row for which every value creates a rectangle with an even number of each digit. So the maximum-sized square which creates the worst case input may be this 63x63 matrix:

```
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,7,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,7,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,8,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,7,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,7,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
4,5,4,6,4,5,4,7,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,8,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,7,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,9,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,7,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,8,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,7,4,5,4,6,4,5,4
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,7,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,7,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,8,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,7,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,7,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
5,6,5,7,5,6,5,8,5,6,5,7,5,6,5,9,5,6,5,7,5,6,5,8,5,6,5,7,5,6,5,1,5,6,5,7,5,6,5,8,5,6,5,7,5,6,5,9,5,6,5,7,5,6,5,8,5,6,5,7,5,6,5
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,7,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,7,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,8,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,7,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,7,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
4,5,4,6,4,5,4,7,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,8,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,7,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,9,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,7,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,8,4,5,4,6,4,5,4,7,4,5,4,6,4,5,4
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,7,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,7,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,8,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,7,3,4,3,5,3,4,3,6,3,4,3,5,3,4,3
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,7,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,6,2,3,2,4,2,3,2,5,2,3,2,4,2,3,2
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,6,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,3,1,2,1
0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0
```

If this is indeed the largest input without rectangles with even numbers of each digit (but I have no proof, and I've only considered square matrices), then that would put a maximum of 3,015,680 on the number of rectangles to be checked, and the worst case complexity would also become O(N) for large input (greater than 1736x1736). (See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2467983/is-63-times63-the-largest-matrix-with-no-rectangles-that-have-an-even-number-o) on Mathematics.)

Comment: What is `N` ? total number of cells?

Comment: @PhamTrung Indeed. The average case maxing out around 1388 for random input is of course linked to the probability of 10 coin tosses giving all heads. If my algorithm were further optimized, that should get down to 1024. Whether the worst case is actually possible for large input is something I still have to look into.